# What case (upper/lower) is preferred in REST scenarios?

Tags: rest

I'm reading the API for [arin](https://www.arin.net/resources/restful-interfaces.pdf) and notice that many of the REST parameters are in uppercase.

Is there a standard that defines what I should be expecting in REST-full service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP (RFC2616) spec [states](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.3) that everything other than the scheme and the host of an URL should be case sensitive.

I realize this part of the spec is regularly ignored, but that's the official word.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The REST principle is based on the original ideas of the HTTP protocol, and it doesn't restrict parameter names to be case sensetive, case insensetive, upper case or lower case.

First you should decide if you want the parameters to be case sensetive or not. Perhaps the system that you are using makes either one a natual choise. (Other than that, I can't really think of a good reason to make them case sensetive.)

Then you should decice a casing that goes well with your resource addresses. If your addresses are in all lowercase, then it might look better if the parameter names are too.